# What is the current understanding of the substrate(s) to the Indo-Aryan languages

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-aryan, substrate

The Indo-Aryan languages have acquired some vocabulary and other features that aren't present in the Iranian languages.

This is ascribed to substrate influence. What is the current understanding of those substrates?

Comment: Since I am a novice I don't get half of your question and want to understand it. Please tell me which features, as in give some examples?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substratum_in_the_Vedic_language

Comment: There are substrate words in Prakrit in buddhistic sanskrit texts, I once read and I'd like to find that source again. This might have influenced synonyms to be reinterpreted as sound change, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 7):

It is generally accepted that there is a significant Dravidian substrate in Indo-Aryan, and a smaller number of substrate words from Austroasiatic languages like Munda and Khasi. There is a chapter on “Loanwords in Sanskrit” in Burrow’s famous book “The Sanskrit Language”, which you should be able to find in a good library.

Comment: Right. That's where the retroflex consonant system comes from, for instance. It's generally accepted that the Indus Valley civilization was Dravidian; there is still at least one Dravidian language spoken in the area. Though most of the other languages are in south India.

Comment: @jlawler. The Indus Valley script has still not been deciphered so it is not known what sort of language it represents. So I would say not "generally accepted" but "widely hypothesized". It has been argued that Brahui arrived in North-Western India only a few centuries ago. If correct, there would be no evidence for an ancient Dravidian presence in that region.

Comment: @jlawler I have yet to see any decisive evidence for retroflexes in Indo-Aryan being the result of Dravidian influence. It is not restricted to Dravidian loans, and in fact, occurs in some Indo-European and Indo-Iranian roots. In fact, the precise phonetics of Indo-Aryan and Dravidian retroflexes differ, they also obey different phonotactics, and Indo-Aryan (especially Dardic) has retroflexes that don't occur in any Dravidian language.

Comment: Retroflexes are undoubtedly an aerial feature of South Asia, but it makes no sense to call it Dravidian influence; might as well be Burushaski influence or Nihali influence, or some other language family that we don't have records of.